# Why AR Object.clone have this phantom behavior?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, clone

I have an active record model like this:
`@model = ModelClass.find(1)`

Then I clone it and make modification:
`@clone = @model.clone`

Then I change the clone:
`@clone.firstname = 'new name'`

But then `@model.firstname` is changed to 'new name' as well. My eyes are almost jump out of my head when I saw this.

Why `clone` bring such a weird behavior?